# What's the difference between All, Most, and Only Important updates on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When you are friends with someone on Facebook you have the option of showing all, most, or only important updates from them. What's the difference between the three?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **All Updates:** Every single update.
- **Most Updates:** What you usually see on your home page.
- **Only Important Updates:** Network events that really matter – if a friend or family member gets a new job, changes relationship status, attends a new university or updates their profile with the joyous news of a new addition to their family.

Comment: There is a separate setting for the types of updates, so how do these settings interact?  How is **Only Important** different than choosing only **Life Events**?  And which updates are excluded from *what you usually see on your home page*?

Comment: The above three (All Updates, Most Updates, Only Important Updates) are to choose _how much_ the updates will get displayed. In other words, it's a _frequency_ setting. Life Events, Photos and Videos, etc. are to choose _what type_ of content will get displayed. For example, if you untick _Life Events_, they will never get displayed no matter what _frequency_ you choose.